# Unable to log in using Chrome after adding another login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid

I set up a StackExchange account (as well as sub accounts on stackoverflow, serverfault, etc) using my work email. After answering a few questions, I realized I should probably associate my account to a personal email.

I found I had previously set up an account with my personal email and deleted it. Then I associated the personal address with this current account in hopes of eventually removing my work email (are you following this?).

Just to test that all went well, I tried to sign in using another browser (Chrome). When I try to sign in using either my personal or work email addresses, I am greeted by the "Oops! Something bad happened!" page, and thereafter am unable to access any of the stack exchange sites.

I [still] logged in through Firefox and afraid to log out for fear of not gaining access again.

I have cleared all data associated with Chrome (even did a reinstall--but then it's a Mac, so it was probably fake) and the problem persists.

What can I do to ensure that my account is set up correctly and that I will not lose access? Is this an OpenID issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aaaaand.... fixed.

The short version of what happened is that because you had two profiles and tried to reuse the credentials from one in another, even though it was deleted, we attempted an account merge behind the scenes. Something went wrong during that merge (not sure *what*, specifically, but I'll try to track it down tomorrow), and you ended up with a broken account.

This should be fixed now and you should be able to log in from any browser. Sorry 'bout that, and enjoy! =)